# Create a django home page

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

How to create django home page , with base.html , I ask for a simple sample, and routing ?

I have already tried , to chreate sample code for home

how to continue
Thankyou,

Answer (score 0):

Simply. you can make a Home page as Base.html .